# Wifi Direct getFragmentmanager method inconvertible types

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-wifi, wifi-direct

Using the WifiDirectDemo sample, I tried to implement it into my own app, but I have one error I cannot find an answer to.

```
    DeviceListFragment fragmentList = (DeviceListFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list);

    DeviceDetailFragment fragmentDetails = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_detail);
```

Android Studio tells me that they are inconvertible types, cannot cast android.fragment to com.example.myapp.DeviceListFragment

This fragment, DeviceListFragment and DeviceDetailFragment are both copied from the Demo, and after double checking I cannot seem to resolve this issue. Everything else is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Both the Fragments are probably from android.support.v4.app.Fragment. So instead of using getFragmentManager() use getSupportFragmentManager() which will return the right kind of fragment that is convertible.

```
DeviceListFragment fragmentList = (DeviceListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list);

DeviceDetailFragment fragmentDetails = (DeviceDetailFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_detail);
```